# ¿Cómo utilizar variables de un método en otro en Java?

Tags: java

Buenas noches, tengo este fragmento de código que tengo en un método llamado **seleccionar()** y quiero poder usar ese valor **(eleccion)** que le asigno dentro de otro método llamado **alimentar()**.

```
     System.out.println("Eliga número de Pokemon: ");
     eleccion = entrada.nextInt();

     System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[eleccion - 1].getNombre());
```

La cuestión es que cuando entro el método que he llamado **alimentar()** el valor **eleccion** que asigné por teclado se ha perdido y por lo tanto pierdo la figura que elegí en el anterior método.

```
 System.out.println("Selecciones actividad: ");
    opcion = entrada.nextInt();

    switch(opcion){

        case 1:
            System.out.println(eleccion);
           System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[eleccion + 1].getNombre());
```

He intentado hacer la variable eleccion global pero el problema me persiste. ¿Existe algún método en java que resuelva esto?

Primeramente tengo un menú con dos métodos activos.

```
   System.out.println("1. Seleccionar Pokemon");
   System.out.println("2. Alimentar y ejercitar");       

   System.out.println("Seleccione opción:");
         opcion = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
            case 1:

                seleccion();

                break;

            case 2:

                alimentacion();

                break;
```

*Las líneas de código que describí anteriormente están en una clase aparte llamada Principal*. Las siguientes líneas corresponden al código que coloqué al principio de este post en una clase Juego.

**Método seleccionar()**

```
  int pokemon2;
    for (pokemon2 = 0; pokemon2 < 5; pokemon2++) {
        System.out.println((pokemon2 + 1) + "." + pokemon[pokemon2].getNombre());
    }   


    System.out.println("Eliga número de Pokemon: ");
    eleccion = entrada.nextInt();

    System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[eleccion - 1].getNombre());
```

**Método alimentar()**

```
  System.out.println("Seleccione alimento o actividad para el pokemon:\n");
    System.out.println("1. Tacos.");

  switch(opcion){
          case 1:
            System.out.println(eleccion);
           System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[eleccion + 1].getNombre());
```

Es en éstas últimas líneas de código cuando pierdo el valor que supuestamente registré en **seleccionar()** que describí con anterioridad. **El valor que me manda cuando corro el método alimentar en el case: 1  es  0 ó bien dicho el personaje que me manda en ese instante es el que almaceno en 0**. Si yo selecciono por ejemplo el 5 en **seleccionar()** sigue dándome 0 en **alimentar()**.   ¿Existe algún método en Java que solucione esto?

Comment: Podrías poner algo mas de código como para poder clarificar un poco como llamas a las funciones y que devuelve cada una?

Comment: He tomado tu consideración, gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar una classe estática con una variable global estática que indique el pokemon actual que usas

Answer (score 1):

Lo que deberias hacer es devolver los valores al metodo que llama.

```
class Principal {
    int elPokemon;

    public int seleccionar() {
        ...
        System.out.println("Eliga número de Pokemon: ");
        eleccion = entrada.nextInt();

        System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[eleccion - 1].getNombre()); 
        // Devolves el valor de eleccion
        return eleccion;
    }
    public void alimentar(int poke) {
         // Tu codigo
         System.out.println("***********Usted eligió a:************\n "+ pokemon[poke + 1].getNombre())
    }
    public void menu() {

        ...
        System.out.println("1. Seleccionar Pokemon");
        System.out.println("2. Alimentar y ejercitar");       

        System.out.println("Seleccione opción:");
        opcion = entrada.nextInt();

        switch (opcion) {
        case 1:
            // Guardas en "elPokemon" el valor que devolves mas arriba con "return eleccion"
            elPokemon = seleccion();

            break;

        case 2:
            // Le pasas el valor de elPokemon para ser usado dentro de alimentacion.
            alimentar(elPokemon);
            break;
    }
}
```

El código va a modo de ejemplo, no lo probé, pero debería funcionar.

Comment: Podrías explicarme que significa la línea  ' public void alimentacio(int pokemon) {'  .  En mi codigo pokemon es el nombre del vector, y busco saber el nombre del personaje que ocupa  el vector según el numero que selecciné.

Comment: @angel_elias te agregue un par de comentarios y minimo ejemplo en alimentar a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: ese poke no debería ser eleccion? ¿Qué valor tiene poke?

Comment: `eleccion` y  `entrada` no están declaradas, no se entiende si on variables locales al método o propiedades de la clase - entender lo cual es el quid de la pregunta, creo yo

Comment: @leonbloy el objetivo del ejemplo era mostrarle como podía solucionar su problema, no la solución en si. Parte del código es de lo que se compartió en la pregunta.

Comment: @JuanM.Hidalgo Ok, pero el caso es que, justamente, aclarar el tema del scope de las variables es importante en el contexto de lo que se pregunta.